# Refreshing a list of webelements after delete line

Tags: list, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing an automated test for a dynamic webtable using Selenium Webdriver with chromedriver and testNG.

The objective is to assert that a certain table-entry is there, delete it if it is, and then assert if it is deleted. This second assert is not working properly however.

During the first assert I call the method that creates a list of Webelements and gets the number of rows. I use this number to know when to stop iterating through the table.
The second assert uses the same table to do the same thing, but now the DOM has changed, en there are only 18 rules left in my table were there were 19 before. As soon as the iteration tries to get the 19th row I get the following:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tr[19]/td[1]"}

I have tried creating a new instance of the MyWishlistPage, but this new instance also sees the "old" number of table rules

I have also tried a thread sleep and a driver refresh after the row delete, but this doesn't help either (piece of code is still there, commented)

I ended up altering my test class to go to another page and then return to the MYWishlistPage. This works, but it's a sloppy workaround that I'm not happy with

Can anyone tell me how I can get the correct number of rows after deleting an entry from the table?

This is a piece of the class for the page that I have the problem with :

```
public class MyWishlistsPage 
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    public MyWishlistsPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;

        //This call sets the WebElements
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public Boolean isWishlistAvailable(String nameToAssert)
    {
        //This list gets the number of rows from the table
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));

        //This loop finds the first row which' title matches sRowValue
        for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) 
        {
            String sValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + i + "]/td[1]")).getText();
            if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(nameToAssert))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public void deleteWishlistsEntry (String sRowValue) 
    {

        //This list gets the number of rows from the table
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));

        //This loop finds the first row which' title matches sRowValue
        for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++)
        {
            String sValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + i + "]/td[1]")).getText();
            if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(sRowValue)) 
            {
                // If the sValue matches with the description, the element in the seventh column of the row will be clicked
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + i + "]/td[7]/a/i")).click();
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

            /*  try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) 
                {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                driver.navigate().refresh(); */
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is a piece of the testclass I am calling the page from :

```
 Assertions.assertThat(mywishlistspage.isWishlistAvailable(listToAssert)).as("The list you were trying to delete did not exist, and an attempt to create it failed ").isTrue();

//Deletes the chosen list
 mywishlistspage.deleteWishlistsEntry(listToAssert);

 //Verifies that list has been deleted
 //homepage.clickMyAccountPage();
 //myaccountpage.goToMyWishlistsPage();
  Assertions.assertThat(mywishlistspage.isWishlistAvailable(listToAssert)).as("The list you tried to delete is still there").isFalse();
```

Comment: Can you share the site URL?

Answer (score 0):

In the deleteWishlistsEntry, First it get the number of rows, after clicking on the "anchor" the line item will be deleted, after that u have to break / exit from that loop once it clicked on the anchor tag... But in the code u r looping until the 19th element that is why u get "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tr[19]/td[1]"}"

```
public void deleteWishlistsEntry (String sRowValue) 
{

    //This list gets the number of rows from the table
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));

    //This loop finds the first row which' title matches sRowValue
    for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++)
    {
        String sValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + i + "]/td[1]")).getText();
        if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(sRowValue)) 
        {
            // If the sValue matches with the description, the element in the seventh column of the row will be clicked
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + i + "]/td[7]/a/i")).click();
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            break;

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will help me. If the element is not there anymore, the IF statement Will never be satisfied and the break you suggest will never be reached.

Comment: if the element does not exist? then why u need to perform click action to delete and accepting the alert... can u please explain the scenario

Comment: After the element is deleted, I am not trying to click it anymore. I am just verifying it isnt there anymore

Comment: Sorry, I see it now. I misread and thought you addded the break in the iswishlistavailable methode. I added it in the deleteWishlistMethod as you suggested, buy this does not help. I think the problem is that the isWishlistAvailable methode gets the number of rows before the entry is deleted. Added a break does not change this. I need a way of refreshing the list

Comment: Sorry on seeing the webpage only able to understand your requirement... Actually your code is correct.. have to check the DOM behavior